Exception Details: System.Exception: This schema for this assembly has not been registered with WMI
Buen día estoy programando en Genexus Ev3 y estoy probando mi aplicativo en IIS 10 cuando intento compilar el rograma me genera el siguiente eror ¿Alguien que me pueda apoyar para ver cual sería la solución?:
"
Server Error in '/TravelAgency.NetEnvironment' Application.
This schema for this assembly has not been registered with WMI.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Exception: This schema for this assembly has not been registered with WMI.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:
herramientas administrativas
[Exception: This schema for this assembly has not been registered with WMI.]
   System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.Initialize(Assembly assembly) +337
   System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.GetInstrumentedAssembly(Assembly assembly) +103
   System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.GetPublishFunction(Type type) +35
   System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation.Publish(Object instanceData) +120
   GeneXus.Performance.WMIDataStoreProviders..ctor() +38
   GeneXus.Performance.WMIDataStoreProviders.Instance() +69
   GeneXus.Performance.WMIDataStoreProvider..ctor(String datastoreName) +14
   GeneXus.Data.NTier.DataStoreProvider..ctor(IGxContext context, IDataStoreHelper dataStoreHelper, Object[][] cursorParms) +365
   GeneXus.Programs.customer.initialize() +2588
   GeneXus.Programs.customer.webExecute() +48
   GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.webExecuteEx() +38
   GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +551

[Exception: GXApplication exception]
   GeneXus.Http.GXHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +681
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8974; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8975
"
